# Upgraded to Az modules from AzureRM now cannot login with Runbook

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I have just started looking at Azure Automation and created my first Runbook today and everything was working fine.  I then read that AzureRM was replaced with the Az module so thought I had better migrate my Runbook and get straight onto the new stuff!

My original code was working absolutely fine using the AzureRM modules, but since upgrading to the latest Az modules I just can't authenticate.  My automation account is exactly the same from a configuration perspective other than I have added in all of the matching Az modules to allow me to use them in my run books.

```
{
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name 'AzureRunAsConnection'

    $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantID
    $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationID
    $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint

    Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal `
        -Tenant $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantID `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationID `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint

    Write-Verbose "Connected to Azure using Automation Connection" -verbose
}
```

I currently get the following error and am at a complete loss as to the reason, documentation is very thin on the ground and the bits I have found simply show what I already have!

```
should be present. If you are accessing as application please make sure service principal is properly created in the 
tenant.
At Do-Authentication:9 char:9
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Connect-AzAccount], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh lord how many times do I answer my own question right after posting it!!!

I did attempt to delete some modules from the list that is the AzureRM ones, I didn't think it let me do it so I ended up just leaving them, I have no idea whether that is relevant or not but thought I'd mention it.

On the Automation Account blad within the Azure portal I clicked on the "Run as accounts" option and it said it was incomplete, I deleted and recreated it and now everything works OK.

Might help someone else so thought I'd post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things to consider while the Az module in Azure Automation. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/az-modules) doc talks about these in greater detail. There is also a note that is worth quoting, from the same doc:

[image: Important Note]

Hope this helps.